# How to call a method of js instance in cljs

Tags: clojure, clojurescript, shadow-cljs

I'm very new to the cljs. I'm practicing the cljs with re-frame. I faced an issue to access a method of js instance.

```clj
(->> quill-contents
    (.parse js/JSON)
    (.setContents @editor))
```

If I tried to call `.setContents` of @editor which is the js instance wrapped with `r/atom` (actually, it is the Quill editor instance). Actually, this code works fine in dev mode, but it throws an error, such as `xi(...).hi is not a function` after making a release build.

I guess that `.setContents` is compiled to `.hi` in the release build, so it can't find the method from the js instance.

I'm using `shadow-cljs` to build this re-frame project.

How can I fix this issue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is due to lacking externs. Add `^js` in front of `@editor`:

```
(->> quill-contents
    (.parse js/JSON)
    (.setContents ^js @editor))
```

It will automatically generate an extern for `setContents` in this case.